# Forward This E-Mail PHP Script?

Tags: php, html, email, forward

Does anyone know where and or how I can build a PHP Script for a Newsletter that would allow the end-user to Forward their received E-Mail to a friend or so?

Basically, allowing them to take the entire body and subject of the e-mail and open up a new E-Mail Draft which would allow them to enter in the contacts they want to forward the e-mail to?

I am fully aware that this function is available in most, if not all, e-mail clients to this day. But it is requested that this functionality be added within the newsletter.

Any guidance? Any concepts? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If the email is already *in* the  user's email client *why* do you need to replicate functionality that's available in that client (in which they're currently working) with a separate script? Also: how do you expect to run this php script in the user's email client?

Comment: @David Thomas: Well as I noted above "I am fully aware that this function is available in most, if not all, mail clients to this day. But it is requested that this functionality be added within the newsletter". I expect to run this script from an external source.

Comment: So, clicking on the "Forward to friend" link would direct the user to a page that would contain a form to fill out and email theri friends?

Comment: I saw that; my asking 'why do you need...' wasn't necessarily directed at you, but I could have been more precise, so allow me to rephrase: why do your clients require you to implement this feature? If you can explain their reasoning there might be a better way to implement what they want. Because, currently, what they want is, or *seems* to be, quite silly.

Comment: Wouldn't any forward functionality be dependent on the email client the end user is using (and complicate something like that significantly)?

Comment: You're on to a loser with this one. You'd need to know what client/OS everybody has and be able to run a script/macro on that client when most email clients guard against that. Sometimes you have to be able to say 'no it can't be done'.

Comment: @Paul: Yes that is completely correct!

Comment: @DavidThomas: I do not know what they require this feature be implemented. It seems more redundant (the bad redundancy) to me if anything, but it is requested of them.

Comment: @vascowhite: Oh I won't be running it off of the e-mail client, the Script will be running off an external source which will have form in which the user will fill out.

Comment: aah, I get it. I think you need to add a bit to your question then :)

Comment: I'm beginning to feel like I'm picking on you, and if that's how it appears please accept my apologies; but did you ask them? Or explain the redundancy to them? Sigh...clients... =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd need to do the following:

1. in your email create a "Forward to friend" link that directs the user to a php page on a remote server.
2. On the remote page, create a script that would contain a form asking for the email address of the friends to email.
3. Use the mail() function (Or 3rd party class) to mail the users

EDIT:

You can take it another step further by using one of Google's API's to automatically grab email addresses from the users account (Like LinkedIn etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ZF's Mail class](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html), which allows to fetch emails using POP3 or IMAP and finally decompose emails into parts.

The [ZF documentation page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html) provides **extensive sample code**.

Answer (score 1):

Add link to email which directs user to a web page that contains

```
<form action="sendmails.php"> 
<input name="sendto" type="text"/> 
...
```

and send more letters from there..